# Linear Algebra: solving minimization problems using orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I'm learning about the application of orthogonal projections in solving minimalization problems, and need help clarifying the example below.

Page 113 below lists out some definitions and theorems, and the bottom half of page 114 is the example.

[image]
[image]
[image]

My questions are as follows:

1. What does the expression $C = U \oplus U^\perp$ mean? From the definitions of $C$ and $U$, I understand that $U$ is a subspace of $C$, but intuitively I don't get what $U^\perp$ is, and how its direct sum with $U$ is the whole $C$. To use the example in the text, if $v = sin(x)$ is in $C$, and $u$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and degree at most 5, what is $u^\perp$ and how are the three things related?
2. Why the inner product 6.39? Can we use any inner product?
3. How are the two ideas marked in red related? In particular, in my understanding we are considering the whole interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, and I don't see how this information is encoded in the simple expression $||v - u||$.

Comment: $U\oplus U^\perp$ means together with it's orthogonal complement. The complement is what is lacking to build up the rest of the space which is not in the subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By definition$$U^\perp=\{v\in V\,|\,(\forall u\in U):\langle u,v\rangle=0\}.$$It's therefore the space of all elements of $V$ which are orthogonal to each element of $U$. And $U\cap U^\perp=\{0\}$, from which it follows that you can form a direct sum with them.
2. Because it is with *this* inner product that you have $\|f\|=\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$, where$$\|f\|=\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^\pi\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert^2\,\mathrm dx}$$
3. Because, in this context,$$\|u-v\|=\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^\pi\bigl\lvert u(x)-v(x)\bigr\rvert^2\,\mathrm dx}.$$